# Python error when packages (traits) are imported even if there are correctly installed

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've installed [pandora.ez](http://pandora.lambrate.inaf.it/docs/ez/quick-guide.html) on Ubuntu 18.04. The installation seems to be completed without errors. I added pandora/lib, pandora/include and pandora/bin to the PATH list. When I run pandora.ez I get this error:

```
angora@angoraubuntu:~$ pandora.ez
[ERR] Error loading package pandora.ez. The package is missing or has some installation problems.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/angora/Pandora/bin/pandora.ez", line 341, in invoke
    pack = pm.loadPackage(pack_name)
  File "/home/angora/Pandora/envs/pandora.ez/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fase/system/inline/PackMan.py", line 68, in loadPackage
    module = __import__(name)
  File "/home/angora/Pandora/envs/pandora.ez/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandora/ez/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from EZ import EZ
  File "/home/angora/Pandora/envs/pandora.ez/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandora/ez/EZ.py", line 48, in <module>
    from traits.api import *
ImportError: No module named traits.api
```

but if I try to import `traits` in the python shell:

```
angora@angoraubuntu:~$ python
Python 2.7.15+ (default, Oct  7 2019, 17:39:04) 
[GCC 7.4.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import traits
>>>
```

i.e. I can import traits without any problem. Thus, how I can make visible installed packages in python to pandora.ez?